# How do I get from Bali airport (Denpasar) to Ubud?

Tags: bali

I have heard that you can book a car or taxi and get a good rate, but how to book?

Walking out the door of the airport into the melee of drivers is daunting and I want to know how much to expect to pay etc so as to be able to negotiate properly.

The hotel does not do pickups.

In general the advice I have heard is to use a BlueBird taxi that has a meter. Is this true for a long trip such as to Ubud.

Edit:
While in Bali I was recommended to pre-book a taxi from Ubud Taxi to meet you at the airport. Person I spoke to paid 270,000rp.

One would hope that they might have a fare coming down from Ubud.

We had a great holiday. People so friendly and food great.

Comment: I'm now back from Bali. I found that once armed with the appropriate fare all taxi drivers we dealt with came to the party and were very pleasant. Fares ranged from 70c for a short hop to $50 for the full day scenic tour. One even came and found me with my shopping that I left in his taxi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [clearly posted fixed rates for airport taxis](http://www.balistoreluggage.com/blog/bali-airport-taxi-new-2015-rates/).  As of 2015, the fixed rate from airport to Ubud is Rp 300,000.  This is slightly expensive but not entirely unreasonable, as a regular metered fare would be around Rp 200,000.

There are other options, in roughly descending order of recommendability:

1. I know this isn't an option for you, but most visitors should **arrange a transfer with their lodgings** in Ubud.  Their rate will likely be comparable or cheaper and, unlike the taxi, they will know *exactly* how to get to your destination!
2. Local Uber clones **Go-Jek** and **Grab** operate in Bali.  Fares from airport to Ubud start around Rp 150,000, subject to vehicle type, surge pricing etc.
3. Walk out the airport to the main road and **hail a regular taxi**.  Unlikely to be worth the effort, and many will hesitate to go to Ubud as they will have a hard time getting a fare back.
4. AFAIK there is **no public transport** directly from the airport to Ubud, although you could catch a bus to Denpasar city and transfer there. Not recommended if you've come off a long flight and aren't already familiar with Indonesian public transport.

And it should go without saying that you should *not* go with one of the random touts hunting for customers in the arrivals hall!

Comment: Thanks for this useful information. The link you provide is interesting.

Comment: FYI: This answer was written in 2016. Now Uber is no longer operating in South East Asia including Bali, as it's South East Asia business had been transferred to Grab.

Answer (score -1):

I went to Bali for vacation last month and stayed at Como Sambala Resort. After searching for taxi to Ubud, I found a local site [Bali Transfer](https://balitransfer.net) offering pre-booked taxi service. I was told that Ubud has 2 price options - one for Ubud center and one for outside Ubud center. As our resort's location was outside Ubud center, the price was 350K/car. On reaching, the driver was waiting for us at the flight information counter with a sign. The ride was easy to find and smooth.